# PreSignUp failed with error RequestId: d4873e11-6a6a-44b6-a802-254be9d7d547 Process exited before completing request

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cognito

I am creating a ReactJS application where AWS Cognito API's is using for Login and Registration but i am facing a issue in Registration module.

PreSignUp failed with error RequestId: d4873e11-6a6a-44b6-a802-254be9d7d547 Process exited before completing request.